# Cuckoo sandbox - Failure in AnalysisManager.run

Tags: ubuntu, debian, malware

I have cuckoo running on Debian 10 with an Ubuntu guest VM. I submit a file for analysis, it runs and says "reported" but the report loads a 404 page. I see the following on the cuckoo server:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/cuckoo/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cuckoo/core/scheduler.py", line 755, in run
    self.launch_analysis()
  File "/home/cuckoo/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cuckoo/core/scheduler.py", line 639, in launch_analysis
    machinery.stop(self.machine.label)
  File "/home/cuckoo/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cuckoo/machinery/physical.py", line 106, in stop
    output = subprocess.check_output(args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 223, in check_output
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd, output=output)
CalledProcessError: Command '['net', 'rpc', 'shutdown', '-I', u'192.168.0.161', '-U', '<redacted>%<redacted>', '-r', '-f', '--timeout=5']' returned non-zero exit status 255
```

The agent is running on the guest vm and all other actions seem to work, the cuckoo server is able to communicate with it.

```
2023-08-30 13:55:05,582 [cuckoo.machinery.physical] DEBUG: Getting status for machine: ubuntusrv20.
2023-08-30 13:55:05,606 [cuckoo.machinery.physical] DEBUG: Machine already running: ubuntusrv20.
2023-08-30 13:55:05,691 [cuckoo.core.guest] INFO: Starting analysis #46 on guest (id=ubuntusrv20, ip=192.168.0.161)
2023-08-30 13:55:05,721 [cuckoo.core.guest] DEBUG: ubuntusrv20: waiting for status 0x0001
2023-08-30 13:55:19,199 [cuckoo.core.guest] DEBUG: ubuntusrv20: status ready
2023-08-30 13:55:19,218 [cuckoo.core.guest] DEBUG: Uploading analyzer to guest (id=ubuntusrv20, ip=192.168.0.161, monitor=latest, size=30535)
2023-08-30 13:55:19,275 [cuckoo.core.guest] DEBUG: ubuntusrv20: analyzer started with PID 3038
2023-08-30 13:58:18,375 [cuckoo.core.guest] DEBUG: ubuntusrv20: analysis not completed yet (status=2)
2023-08-30 13:58:19,412 [cuckoo.core.guest] INFO: ubuntusrv20: end of analysis reached!
2023-08-30 13:58:19,472 [cuckoo.core.plugins] DEBUG: Stopped auxiliary module: Replay
2023-08-30 13:58:19,515 [cuckoo.core.plugins] DEBUG: Stopped auxiliary module: Sniffer
```

Thanks in advance.